# Pass multiple values in $scope object in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am new in Angular.js and want to know more about it.
I just created a small project And want to pass multiple value with $scope object.
But it's not working properly.

Here what I am doing

```
function ListCtrl($scope, $http,Project) {
    $http.get('/project').success(function(data){
     str =data.result;
     var result= str.replace('http://','domainname');
     $scope.projects=data.rows;
     $scope.projects=data.result;
  });
}
```

In data variable I am getting rows and result.
And I am passing something like above with $scope.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two will overwrite each other.

```
$scope.projects=data.rows;
$scope.projects=data.result;
```

What you want to do might be more like this.

```
$scope.projects = {};
$scope.projects.rows = data.rows;
$scope.projects.result = data.result;
```

Then in your html if you want to display these, you can use ng-repeat to iterate over them and display each element. Do you have HTML to go with this that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$scope.projects = {};

$scope.projects.rows = data.rows;
$scope.projects.result = data.result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that the view is not informed about the changes of the `$scope.data` variable, due to the fact that the value is changed in the async callback of the `Promise` which is returned by the `$http.get()` method.

Just wrap your `$scope` changes in a `$scope.$apply` method to run the digest loop:

```
$http.get('/project').success(function(data){
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        // Do scope changes here
    })
}
```

Additionally you are assigning the value `$scope.projects` twice, so change this:

```
$scope.projects = {};
$scope.projects.rows = data.rows;
$scope.projects.results = data.result;
```

or just:

```
$scope.projects = data;
```